# How does the use of 1x1 convolutional layers represent permutation in the GLOW model?

Tags: deep-learning, convolution, generative-models

I am currently reading the GLOW paper (found [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1807.03039)) and I can not understand how the authors claim that the use of 1x1 convolutional layers is equivalent to permutation holds true.

I understand how a set of 1x1 convolutions on an image with more than a single channel change the dimensions of the input. However, I don't see how this procedure keeps the original values and only rearranges them, which is what I'd expect a permutation process to do.